# CSS change height on :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to change the height and position of an anchor `<a>` on hover.

The CSS I am using is:

```css
    .options {
     background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #dbe2e8);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 115px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
 }

    .options:hover {
        height: 39px;
  top: -4px;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="options"></a>
```

I must be doing something wrong.  I have tried the :hover part with just the `top: -4px;` and this works, however the `height: 39px;` does nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add the HTML code?

Comment: the height changes on hover, what is the real issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative` also because `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties work only when applied with position `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

```css
.options {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #dbe2e8);
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 115px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.options:hover {
    height: 39px;
    top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="options">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I do have relative positioning set to all div's and a's earlier in the css.  I will add the HTML to my question.  I see it works in your snippet but I'm not getting that effect in mine for some reason (hence the frustration).

Comment: @Mike : Can you reproduce the issue by updating the code.

Comment: @Mike yes, please show us your current code so that we can try to find out the issue.

Comment: Okay, the entire code is quite lengthy however I am only having the issue with the options in the header.  I have broken down the code and am still getting the same issue, I have it on a jsfiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/p7o4sy6a/1/ . I am trying to move the element up 4px and then compensate by making it 4px larger in height but there is a gap left below the element once it moves up, which tells me the change in height is not working(?).

Comment: plus!! it's only meant to change the one I am hovering over.  It seems to change the height of all the others.

Comment: @Mike You need to modify your structure as with current one, I think its not possible, here is the fiddle you can go through of it and try to understand, If anything confuse you, please feel free to ask why I've used this strucutre https://jsfiddle.net/p7o4sy6a/2/

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through it.  There will probably be bits I do not understand.  The reason I am doing this project is to learn so there is lots that I am not yet grasping.  Most problems I can sort out but this one has really got me.  I'll ask if there's anything I'm unsure of!  Thanks again!

Comment: @MuhammadUsman  Okay, is this right...  is the main "ingredient" to this the `vertical-align: bottom` now in the .options css?  So this lines it at the bottom of it's container so that when the height is increased it simply moves up?  The div and span within the link are there to make sure the text is still centered in the same way I had it, using css table and table-cell display?

Comment: @Mike yes, you are right. Why your first variant was not working? Because you were increasing height of an element having a `table-cell` property. All table cells which are on same level or within same row cannot have different heights. If you will increase height of one cell, others will take that height implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for this. Of course, that makes sense about the table-cell. Appreciate your help, it works great now!

Answer (score 0):

While Muhammad Usman's answer works just fine, I'd like to offer an alternative.

If you replace the top:-4px with translateY(-4px) that will work regardless of the "position" property of the element  and/or the "top" property. 

*(Useful if for example the "top" property is a percentage or set dynamically by JS and you want to move it by 4 pixels no matter what the top is)*

```css
.options {
     background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #dbe2e8);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 115px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
 }

    .options:hover {
        height: 39px;
  transform:translateY( -4px);
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="options"></a>
```